# how to submit value after selecting radio button in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

my view code is here...what is code for controller, plz can anyone explain.

```
   <td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt1']);
      echo $this->Form->radio($i, $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>


    <td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt2']);
      echo $this->Form->radio($i, $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>


    <td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt3']);
      echo $this->Form->radio($i, $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>

    <td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt4']);
      echo $this->Form->radio($i, $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
<td><?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'),array('controller'=>'question')); ?></td>
```

Comment: start with `function whatever() { debug ($this->request->data); }` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that. In your questions controller let's say your form is submitted to '/questions/yourActionMethodName'

Your code should look something like:

```
public function yourActionMethodName(){

    if($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->request->data)){
        $this->Question->create(); //to save a new record
        $this->Question->save($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

This should create a new New record setting the database column value of field 'opt1' to the value selected by the user. I am not sure what's the case you are trying to solve. This should give you an idea of how things saved to database. Tell me more on the case and I could edit the code to match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you need put the model and name of this

```
   <td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt1']);
      echo $this->Form->radio('Model.'.$i.'.name', $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>


    <td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt2']);
      echo $this->Form->radio('Model.'.$i.'.name', $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>


    <td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt3']);
      echo $this->Form->radio('Model.'.$i.'.name', $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>

    <td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt4']);
      echo $this->Form->radio('Model.'.$i.'.name', $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<td><?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?></td>
```

and after in your controller if you need save a lot fields you need use use saveAll or saveMany dep

```
public function Name(){

    if($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->request->data)){
        $this->Question->create();
        $this->Question->save($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you all for your reply..

actually i want to store these rado button value in a column of my table. i.e choosen_answer....after this i want to compare choosen_answer with correct_answer.

Answer (score 0):

well you have to load your model in your controller in order to create a new record in your DB
your view look like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Question');?>
<td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt1']);
      echo $this->Form->radio('Model.'.$i.'.name', $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>


    <td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt2']);
      echo $this->Form->radio('Model.'.$i.'.name', $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>


    <td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt3']);
      echo $this->Form->radio('Model.'.$i.'.name', $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>

    <td><?php $attributes = array();
      $options = array($question['Question']['opt4']);
      echo $this->Form->radio('Model.'.$i.'.name', $options, $attributes);?>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<td><?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?></td>
```

now in your controller you have to load your model before creating a new record

```
public function NameOfYourFunction(){

    $this->loadModel('Question');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {                
            if ($this->Question->save($this->request->data)) {
                  $this->Session->setFlash(__('Information save succesfully.'));
                  return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }

}
```

i hope i helped you